# Xubuntu stuck after 16.10 to 17.10 update

Tags: updates, xubuntu, 17.10

I'm a bit new to this so I'll hope I won't sound to stupid.
I was running Xubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and I finally decided to accept the update request to 17.10.

After the process, the laptop reboot, splash screen shows the "waiting loop" for some time and then I have a black screen and I'm stuck.

I reboot and by pressing the escape key I manage to have a tty (but without NW) so I tried some things I've read here:
- add pci=noaer in grub
- remove .Xauthority in my home (but I don't even get to the prompt so it was probably a stupid try)
- I purge the nvidia drivers just in case

no luck, I'm still stuck.

Do you have any idea how I could find what is wrong and correct it?

Thanks for your help

Update :
I read about the journalctl command so I did that and found this (the seconf line is in red):
input: Asus Wireless Radio Control as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input5 
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource (mem 0xfed40080-0xfed40fff) 
tpm_crb: probe of MSFT0101:00 failed with error -16

Answer (score 0):

I'll reply to myself.

I tried reinstall the nvidia driver but I was still stuck.
So I purged it again and install a previous version (nvidia-381).
It gives me access to my session but I had only a 800x600 resolution.
So in the setting I choose the nouveau driver and then it works !